# Limitate number of string to type in TextField - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to limitate my users to type just 3 words inside my `TextField`. I found some other topic that are talking about to limitate the `char` in input, but it's not what I want.

Does someone know if it's possible to count the space inside the `TextField` and do a kind of if statement if more than 3 spaces are typed you can't write anything else?

> Ex: "Boys rescued in Thailand" should be blocked after "Boys rescued in"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you want to process string from spaces only? Or with several spaces between words.

Comment: With the function "Editing Change"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to hook into textField's delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersIn`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text, text.split(separator: " ").count < 3 {
        return true
    }
    return (string == "" || string != " ")
}
```

Comment: That's looks great... Could I use it inside the reference "Editing Changed"? For limit the input at runtime? Or it's enough to add the function to my code?

Comment: `editingChanged` will get called after the edit has been made. If you want to limit the user, then you probably want to make that check before the editing and disable it if a certain condition holds true. That's why I used `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

Comment: It seems working but there is a problem. After that I typed more than 3 words separated by space, the TextField is stopping to work.

Comment: I'm confused. Wasn't that your question? Your question states that you only want to allow three words to be entered

Comment: Yes, the question is that I want to limitate the input up to three words. But if then the user wants to delete something he can't because the Text Field is disabled. 
And he can't neither tap "Return" for start the process.

Comment: Now it's working, but after the third space it's accepting just one char

Comment: @PietroMessineo Updated again and tested. Please accept the answer if it works

Comment: That's finally perfect!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I bealeave you could have custom validation function that would take the string from field then, split it to array. And check the length of array.

```
var fullName = "First Last"
var fullNameArr = split(fullName) {$0 == " "}
var firstName: String = fullNameArr[0]
var lastName: String? = fullNameArr.count > 1 ? fullNameArr[1] : nil
```

Answer (score 0):

In TextField Delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

do some check like this

```
var wordCount = 0
if let text = textField.text {
    wordCount = text.split(separator: " ").count
}
if wordCount < 3 {
    return true
}
return false
```